# August 2015 Community Challenge

Tags: discussion, fun, community-challenge

> The top-voted answer is [**Racetrack**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5629/): "In the game of Racetrack, cars race around a track bounded by two concentric closed loops drawn on a square grid. Implement a program that plays this game."

It's time to choose a [community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge) for August 2015.

- Post your challenge as an answer to this question. Feel free to resubmit non-winning ideas from previous months.
- Vote for those answers which interest you.
- At the end-of-day on Friday, July 31st, the top-voted post will become the next challenge.

Once the challenge topic is decided, post your solution as a [question on the main site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and tag it with [community-challenge](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-challenge). The challenge runs throughout August (but nothing stops you from posting an entry later on).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the game of [Racetrack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racetrack_(game)), cars race around a track bounded by two concentric closed loops drawn on a square grid:

[image]

Each player has a car at an integer position \$(x, y)\$ on the grid with a velocity vector \$(v_x, v_y)\$ that starts at \$(0, 0)\$. Players take turns to move their cars. A move consists of:

1. updating the velocity vector by adding \$-1\$, \$0\$, or \$+1\$ to each component;
2. moving the car to \$(x + v_x, y + v_y)\$.

So in the game shown above, the green car's velocity vector went \$(1, 0)\$ → \$(1, 1)\$ → \$(1, 2)\$ → \$(0, 3)\$ → \$(0, 4)\$ → \$(1, 4)\$ → \$(1, 4)\$ → \$(0, 5)\$ → \$(-1, 5)\$.

A car that leaves the track or lands on a position occupied by another car crashes. You'll see that the green car is now doomed: it can't brake quickly enough to avoid running off the top of the track. (There are variations on what happens next: in some versions a crashed car loses the game; in others it can reset its velocity to \$(0, 0)\$ and continue.)

Implement a program that plays this game.

Answer (score 11):

In image processing, a *contour* is a closed curve forming the boundary of a region of the image (or a union of closed curves, if the region has holes). For example, given this image:

[image: low-resolution image of a capital letter O]

The contour of the black region is the pair of orange curves shown here:

[image: the contour of the capital letter O consists of two curves, one for the outer boundary and one for the inner boundary]

Implement an algorithm that finds the contour of a region in an image.

You may assume, if you wish, that the image is represented as a two-dimensional array of Booleans (indexed by \$x\$ and \$y\$, say), with array entries containing `true` for the region of interest.

Possible choices of algorithm include:

- [Theo Pavlidis](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/theo.html)
- [Moore-Neighbor](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/moore.html)
- [Marching squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares)

Answer (score 11):

### Implement Jeopardy

[image]

I'd love to see implementations on this classic.

For those who don't know this is the game flow:

- A board is created with several questions.

  - Each column is a different category.
  - The rows increase question value & difficulty.
- User selects a question & category. Correct answers increase their score by the value of the question, incorrect answers decrease their score just the same, *negative scores are possible*.

  - Questions don't have to be answered, but should feature either a time limit or a 'skip' function.
- if multiple players are enabled(*optional*):

  - the player who correctly answered the last question is the one who chooses the next question.
  - If multiple players want to answer, answer priority is given to the one who wanted to answer first and then it goes to the next and so on.
- Play until the board is out of questions.

Pros:

- Well known.
- Can be fully created with just text.

Answer (score 3):

My entry is a FTP server. From there, the quality of the entry is the code & the features included. Can be done in any language, requires no graphical design, and would be a nice challenge.

Comment: Related previous submission: [Write any kind of server](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5242/31562)